# Discrete-to-Continuous Function in Mathematica?

Tags: functions

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633219/continuous-generalization-of-sum-k-0n-n-choose-k-2n) link on SE Math, I began to wonder if Mathematica has a function that attempts to convert a discrete function into a continuous one?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you would like such  a function to do? E.G. input and output.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `Interpolation` or `Fit`?  Or something that would require Mma to have more "creativity" so to speak?

Comment: Two Mathematica function that I think might interest you are [FindFormula](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html) and [FindSequenceFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html)